# Qt Application not working correctly in RHEL 6

Tags: c++, linux, qt, rhel6

I built an application in Qt in RHEL 6. The application is a front end GUI to invoke other applications. I made the application such that when user clicks QPushButton, it emits signal and connects to its respective slot. In the slot I'm using 'system' command to execute a script that will start all background applications in gnome-terminals.

Everything is working fine if I run my application directly from QtCreator or the executable from terminal. But when I double click the executable and click the pushbutton, only one background application gets started and my GUI gets hanged. And if I close that first background application manually by closing the terminal, the next background application is starting and so on. Why the executable is working differently?
And one more interesting thing I found. If I open an empty terminal and then run my application by double clicking it is working perfectly.
I found this [link](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/63149-Difference-between-running-QT-app-with-double-click-or-from-terminal) but no use.

Comment: Can you try starting your application from a terminal? It might provide some additional information.

Comment: I did and its working normally as I mentioned. No info regarding the application. Just some echoes from the script are being printed.